# Can I do this type transformation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```js
type U = {
  foo: {
    id: '001'
    name: 'alan'
  }
  bar: {
    id: '002'
    name: 'dan'
  }
}

type V = {
  '001': 'alan'
  '002': 'dan'
}

// type Trans<T> = ...
// V === Trans<U>
```

Sorry I don't know how to name it, but anyone can tell me how to archive that?

I've already been trying for several hours but I can only get

```js
// this is not I want
type V = {
  '001': 'alan' | 'dan'
  '002': 'alan' | 'dan'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you want `V` to be `{ "001": "alan"; } | { "002": "dan"; }` or `{ "001": "alan"; "002": "dan" }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with a mapped type and a remapped key ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)):

```
type V = {[K in keyof U as U[K]['id']]: U[K]['name']}
// V = { "001": "alan"; "002": "dan" }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqlC8UDeBYAUFKAzA9jgXMuppgJYAmhA5AAw0CMVxJAdgIYC2E1bANmyyYYoAX2YAjNgCdCqYWUpRaNAExCSUdl2rkB60ejFp0oSFABqCZAG0A0lFIsoAawggcWWFDYBnWHYBdayoKKgCAwhhA4K0IMKMAegSLKyQoACI6enTCdL4BdIBuDLoVHIzdFnSDNCA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via mapped types and generics.  Here is my solution:

```
type CollapseKV<T extends Record<PropertyKey, Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>, K extends keyof T[keyof T], V extends keyof T[keyof T]> =
    { [H in keyof T]: { [_ in T[H][K] extends PropertyKey ? T[H][K] : never]: T[H][V] } }[keyof T];

type U = {
  foo: {
    id: '001'
    name: 'alan'
  }
  bar: {
    id: '002'
    name: 'dan'
  }
}

type V = CollapseKV<U, "id", "name">;
//   ^? { "001": "alan"; } | { "002": "dan"; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwQQzAZwgaQGoB4AqUEAHsBAHYAmaUAShAMZwBOluACs3JM6JhCAA0dRizaduEXiH5CoAV3IBrcnADu5AHybhmIqQrUoSgXABmUfAG0TIc5YC6w7PrJUat+9c8X8DzVAAvACwAFBQEVAA3lBWABJQAJbkxqa+DgBc0bEA+kkp1nEOVpgOroY0Ejx8AlAA-JbxxaVQWeQQAG5SmY1FVthlAL5QgzZpjgDcYWGgkFAAqkHRYRFmcHBZUSuRiZRZAOQADIcAjPvbEeTIALYQB8go5OfhI9sARsjMmxdJe1BHhwATM9IlArrcDpRkE9toMwnDQjNwNAXIFYIgUOgsHh5sIAES7PH48EQPGaKahAD0lMiAD0GjE8ccTnisniHtC8RMRlAAD7ZJlA1lQPFQ8hckZAA)

Comment: Sorry but this is not I want, what I need is '001': 'alan'; '001': 'dan',  not 'alan' | 'dan'

Comment: @WW00WW Ah, sorry. Misread the question.  I fixed the code now.